# Set Text Properties of UITableViewCell object dynamically with an array - cellForRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic-arrays

I am a beginner in Objective-C & iPhone development.

I add dynamically cells in a TableView. I want to set labels's text properties with an array. I saw many tutorials, and I searched during several hours but labels are never filled.

My code is :

```
- (void)insertNewObject
{
  for (NSInteger ic=0; ic<((pages.count)); ++ic) {
      NSLog(@"%d", ic);
      NSDictionary *monDico = pages[ic];
      menu = [monDico objectForKey:@"Name"];
      NSIndexPath *indexPathTable = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
      [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathTable] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
      [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]; // I try include & exclude : never call
  }
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.textLabel.text = menu[indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"%@%@", @"Cell Label = ", cell.textLabel.text);
   return cell;
}
```

Please note that insertNewObject method is called during viewDidLoad execution.

I use a breakpoint in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method : it never calls ! I try with :

- explicit calling
- forcing reloadData method

but did not work too.

Can you please tell me why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the `delegate` and `datasource`?

Comment: Are you using a table view controller, or a table view on a view controller?

Comment: I am using a TableViewController in a storyboard with my custom class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to `textLabel` property of your cell, then it must be style of: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`. Or, if you use storyboard, then set Cell's style to Basic.
[image]

And, of course, make sure that you have set `delegate` and `datasource` properties of your tableView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //...

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

------------------EDIT------------------

If you're using UITableViewController, then no more need to set `delegate` and `dataSource` properties manually, because they will automatically set  by UITableViewController when your view did load.

If `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method still not being called, then make sure that following methods that you implemented, both returns value >0:
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;`
and 
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Set a breakpoint before `return` and see returning values, or just NSLog them before returning.

Comment: All of those cell styles have a `textLabel` property, not just the default style.

Comment: Yes, they have, but if cell's style is custom, then there will be no effect when you set text to that property. Because it will be hidden in that case

Comment: But it will still work if it is right detail, left detail, or subtitle. It may show up in different ways in each, but to say it must be set to Basic or must be style default isn't true.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
I said `Basic` because of provided sample code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` by QO. 
There he set property only to `textLabel`, but not to `detailTextLabel` too, so I supposed that he need only Basic style ;)

Comment: I try to set delegate & datasource but still not work. I did not see this in many tutorials. My cells are basic.

Comment: I already test that. They return values. I put my custom code in a new masterDetailApp project and it works, but it is not my goal. I would like to understand why I do not call this method ! :/

Comment: If you send me the project I can look on it :)

Comment: You are nice @arturdev ! This is the link : [link](https://github.com/Karine-GitHub/IOS-Json/commit/88cfbd4fd162d9701adf643405c585ea6eccf393)  Thank you very much !!

Comment: The first thing that I noticed is this:

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections. Here, always 0.
    return 0;
}
  

Here you always return 0, and because of this, `numberOfRowsInSection` will not called, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` too.

So, return a positive number of section, or remove that method at all, because the default value is 1.

Comment: And the second thing,, provide your `APIapplication.json` file that I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

If cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called then most likely you have not set:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menu count];  // indicates the number of rows in your table view
}
```

This method needs to return the number of rows you expect to render within your table view. The default is 0 = no rows. I'm assuming you want to show all the items in your menu array so simply return [menu count].

Check this: [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I try your solution but still not work. I try with including & excluding calls of `delegate`, `datasource`, `reloadData` & `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? Is cellForRowAtIndexPath never being called or is your data not showing up in your tableView? Also, I'm assuming that you've created a UITableViewController class and assigned it to your tableView in IB (storyboard) right?